# Transmission not going into gear until the engine is accelerated to a very high rpm

Tags: automatic-transmission

The car will not move until I put the transmission in low range and accelerate to very high rpm. Please give a place to start looking for the problem.

Comment: Transmission fluid level? Is it a nice red color, or does it look burnt?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your question is too vague. If you want any specific help, you are going to have to tell us more about the car. What make and model is it? What engine?

Comment: It would help to know more about the car and the specific RPM range that top gear is engaging.